# Contenteditable div in Angular js cursor jumps to beginning while typing

Tags: angularjs, position, caret, cursor-position

This is my html editable div below

```
<div id="editorAbstract"
     ng-change="abstractChangeHandler(data.message.data.item.abstract.rawData)" cleanInput ng-blur="OnBlurTitleAbstractChange(this)"
     ng-focus="freeIndexing.freeIndexingTermfocus('editorAbstract')"
     medium-editor bind-options="{toolbar:true,placeholder:{text: '',hideOnClick: true},disableReturn: true,toolbar: {buttons: ['bold','italic','subscript','superscript','uppercase','lowercase','titlecase','removeFormat'],static:true,align: 'left',sticky:true,updateOnEmptySelection: true},disableExtraSpaces: false,fileDragging: true,spellcheck: false,extensions: {'imageDragging': {}},paste: {forcePlainText: true,cleanPastedHTML: false}}" ng-model="data.message.data.item.abstract.rawData" 
     ng-keyup="validateAbstractkeyup($event,data.message.data.item.abstract.rawData)" class="contenteditable">
</div>
```

I have function called `validateabstractkeyup` this function is causing this issue.

```
$scope.validateAbstractkeyup = function (event, model) {
       if (model != null && model != undefined && model != '' &&
       model.indexOf('<span style="font-size: 11.25px;">') > -1) {

           spanTagEndIndex = (model.indexOf('<span style="font-size: 11.25px;">')) + 34;
           closingSpanTagStartIndex = model.indexOf('</span>', spanTagEndIndex);
           spanTagInnerText = model.substring(spanTagEndIndex, closingSpanTagStartIndex);
           stringforreplace = '<span style="font-size: 11.25px;">' + spanTagInnerText + '</span>'
           result = model.replace(stringforreplace, spanTagInnerText);
           $scope.data.message.data.item.abstract.rawData = result;
}
```

`$scope.data.message.data.item.abstract.rawData` (this is bind to `ng-model` for editable div) may be this is getting refresh.

Comment: cursor position jumps to the begning of text any solution in angulr js to retain its cursor position after text change or ng-model data refresh